# C++ Dangling Pointer after return statement

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code and want to know that in the `int *fun()` function after the `return p;` statement I used `p=nullptr;`. I am a bit confused that whether or not the P pointer is pointing to the heap memory or not and if it is how do assign p=nullptr while returning  the address of heap memory it was pointing

```
int *fun(int size)
{
    int *p=new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        p[i]=i+1;
    cout<<p<<endl;
    return p;
    p=nullptr;
}
int main()
{
    //return by address

      int *q=fun(5);
      cout<<q;

      for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
          cout<<q[i];
      }

      delete []q;
      q=nullptr;
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement returns *immediately*. So the assignment never happens. But it's not even needed.

Comment: why is it not needed?

Comment: `p` points at dynamically allocated storage. That's often implemented with a heap.

Comment: Because as soon as the function returns, the variable `p` cease to exist. Its value is copied as the return value and then copied into `q` in the `main` function.

Comment: Why do you want to assign `nullptr` to p?

Comment: Don't return a raw pointer, wrap it into a smart one.

Comment: ok got it thanks a lot

Comment: why do you think you need to do `p = nullptr`?

Comment: I am sure that with "how do assign p=nullptr while returning the address of heap memory it was pointing" we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please explain what you want to achieve by assigning nullptr to the local variable. Then it can be discussed whether achieving that is necessary at all and how to do it.

Comment: I guess that somebody (correctly) told you that all memory aquired via `new` needs to be "handed back". But that needs to be done AFTER it was used outside of the function (i.e. by the caller) and it needs to be done the right way (using `delete`) and the vaule of the pointer is irrelevant for it.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes sir!

Comment: Good. :-) Looking forward to your improvement of the question.